# How to do calibration accounting for resolution of the instrument

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have to calibrate a distance measuring instrument which gives capacitance as output, I am able to use `numpy polyfit` to find a relation and apply it get distance. But I need to include limits of detection 0.0008 m as it is the resolution of the instrument.

My data is:

```
cal_distance = [.1 , .4 , 1, 1.5, 2, 3]
cal_capacitance = [1971, 2336, 3083, 3720, 4335, 5604]
raw_data =  [3044,3040,3039,3036,3033]
```

I need my distance values to be like .1008, .4008 that represents the limits of detection of the instrument.

I have used the following code:

```
coeffs = np.polyfit(cal_capacitance, cal_distance, 1)
new_distance = []
for i in raw_data:
    d = i*coeffs[0] + coeffs[1]
    new_distance.append(d)
```

I have a csv file and actually used a pandas dataframe with date time index to store the raw data, but for simplicity I have given a list here.
I need to include the limits of detection in the calibration process  to get it right.

Comment: This is so vague. Of course you need to get it right, but what is it? You don't demonstrate how they factor in. There are lots of statistical techniques for dealing with non-detect data.

Comment: For example If I have a capacitance value of 3044 and if you look into calibration data the distance should be between 0.4 m to 1 m and If I do the present method I get distance like 0.8967892678 m(for example), instead something like 0.8008(example). Because the instrument will only able to differentiate 0.0008 m. I need to apply a correction like if the value is between the two numbers it is rounded and shows the limits of detection

Comment: Limits of detection and resolution are different. Why not just divide by the resolution, round to an integer value, then convert back?

Comment: so  can I divide the distance by resolution and round it to appropriate decimal places?

Comment: Yeah. In array math it'd be `np.round(x / res) * res`

Answer (score 0):

Limit of detection is the accuracy of your measurement (the smallest 'step' you can resolve) 
polyfit gives you a 'model' of the best fit function f of the relation 
distance = f(capacitance) 
You use 1 as the degree of the polynomial so you're basically fitting a line.

So, first off you need to look into the accuracy of the fit: this is returned by using the 3rd parameter full=True.
(see the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html for more details)
You will get the residual of the fit. 
Is it actually smaller than the LOD? Otherwise your limiting factor is the fitting 
accuracy. In your particular case it looks like it is 0.00017021, so indeed below the 0.0008 LOD.

Second, why 'add' LOD to the reading? Your reading is the reading. then LOD is the +/- range the distance could really be within. Adding it to the end result does not seem to make sense here.
You should instead report the final value as 'new distance' +/- LOD.

Is your raw data all measurements of the same distance? If so, you can see that the standard deviation of this measurement using the fit is 0.0029680362423331122, ( numpy.std(new_distance) ) and range is 0.0087759439302268483, which is 10x over the LOD, so here your limiting factor really seems to be the measuring conditions.

Comment: I have raw_distance values that very from 0 to 2 m, I have only displayed a small sample.

Comment: The capacitance reading apparatus precision and LOD is really what is going to be limiting your capability to measure precise distance. This will show as the residual of the fit. 
I'm not sure what you mean by 'get it right' in the original post, but getting it right is reporting the measured capacitance converted to the distance, with a 'precision' +/- value, which can be determined by the precision of the capacitance measurement transformed through the same fit coeffs.

Comment: https://github.com/Kirubaharan/hydrology/blob/master/ch_591_ver_2_%20daily.py My code is here, can u pls look the function from line 97

Comment: what am I looking for? I explained what you need to do: I don't think you should add the LOD to your measurement. Fit the data, calculate residual / error and report it as part of the measurement result as in Result +/- accuracy.

Comment: Yeah but the issue is I am working on small dams, the capacitance is converted into water level values. If the water level is above 1.9, I assume it is overflowing, but If I dont include LOD then even values above 1.9 might be misrepresented as less than that due to errors, I believe this non inclusion of LOD might create large errors in my overflow and other estimates as everything depends on the accuracy of this conversion

Comment: still, your measurement is measured value +/- LOD. what you need to do is properly qualify this LOD from the capacitance measurement. If then your application requires that you take the lower limit of this measurement for safety, then do so in that calculation, but reporting a value 'offset' by LOD is simply inaccurate.

Comment: How to properly qualify the LOD from capacitance measurement?

Comment: use your raw data of known distances (your calibration set) and apply the fit. you can then see how much variation you have from the actual values (range) and standard deviation (1 sigma)

Comment: this will tell you how precise your measurement really is, regardless of the theoretical LOD of the instrument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68018/discussion-between-kirubaharan-j-and-mre).

Answer (score 0):

Not to beat a dead horse, but LOD and precision are two completely different things.  LOD is typically defined as three-times the standard deviation of the noise of your instrument, which would be equivalent to the minimum capacitance (or distance , which is related to capacitance here) your instrument can detect.  i.e. anything less than that is equivalent to zero (more or less).  But your precision is the minimum **change** in capacitance that can be detected by your instrument, which may or may not be less than the LOD.  Such terms (in addition to accuracy) are common sources of confusion.  While you may know what you are talking about when you say LOD (and everyone else may be able to understand that you really mean precision) it would be beneficial to use the proper notation.  Just a thought...